# systemctl poweroff and reboot do nothing

Tags: centos, systemd, reboot

I have a VirtualBox VM running CentOS 7.7. It is headless and runs some custom services along with the standard ones. When I run `systemctl halt`, `systemctl poweroff` or `systemctl reboot`, it disconnects SSH as connected, but never shuts down or reboots. I am able to still SSH back in and if I run these commands again, they just hang and nothing at all happens. The system logs do not show anything. The only indication I can see that systemd is trying to shut down is that running `systemctl` with no arguments shows the system state as Stopping. However, no services ever seem to stop.

There is probably more information that I can provide, but I don't know what. Let me know in comments what would be helpful and I will provide it as best I can.

If it helps, here is the log file from running `strace -o log.txt systemctl reboot`. There are some EAGAIN errors, but I don't know if those are normal or not.

https://pastebin.com/XC7d0Kt6